# iframe's document is null even though its contentwindow isn't

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have been trying to use `iframe` to load a cross-origin webpage onto my website but it is not functioning as expected. When I load my website, sometimes the iframe doesn't load the webpage at all and when it does load, its `document` is `null`.
Here is the script file (which is included at the end of the `<body>`)

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');

iframe.onload = function() {
    alert('iframe loaded!');
    if(iframe.contentWindow)
    {
        alert('contentWindow checked');
    }
    if(iframe.contentWindow.document)
    {
        alert('document checked');
    }
}
```

When I load the page, I only get the "iframe loaded!" and "contentWindow checked" alerts. This also happens when the webpage doesn't load at all. For some reason the `document` is always `null` even when the webpage loads fine in the `iframe`.
I am using the Chromium web browser.

Comment: Per the console error I get, Chrome blocks access to the cross-origin document.

Comment: You can't access document of cross domain iframe due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: Can I turn it off for any other browser?

Answer (score 2):

The contentWindow property returns the Window object generated by an iframe element (through the window object, you can access the document object and then any one of the document's elements). You can use this Window object to access the iframe's document and its internal DOM. This attribute is read-only. hence iframe.contentDocument.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');

iframe.onload = function() {
    alert('iframe loaded!');
    let contentWindow = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument) //this is better approach
    if(iframe.contentWindow)
    {
        alert('contentWindow checked');
    }
    if(iframe.contentDocument)
    {
        alert('document checked');
    }
}
```